# Recommendation for boolean dataset with apache mahout

Tags: machine-learning, apache-mahout, recommender-system

I was trying to implement Item based Recommender System with the boolean dataset, Dataset example:

```
      User-id | movie-id | Action | Comedy | Drama
        1              200    0         1        1
        2              210    1         1        0
```

And I tried implementing it with item-based similarity algorithm as follows:

```
package prediction.contentrecommender;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.common.TasteException;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.model.file.FileDataModel;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.recommender.GenericItemBasedRecommender;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.similarity.TanimotoCoefficientSimilarity;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.model.DataModel;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.recommender.RecommendedItem;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.similarity.ItemSimilarity;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.recommender.GenericBooleanPrefItemBasedRecommender;


public class ContentRecommender {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int userid=10;
           int noOfRecommendations=1;
           
        
        try {
            
            DataModel dm = new FileDataModel(new File("data/dataset.csv"));
            ItemSimilarity sim = new TanimotoCoefficientSimilarity(dm);
            GenericItemBasedRecommender recommender =
                new GenericBooleanPrefItemBasedRecommender(dm,sim);

         List<RecommendedItem> recommendations =
             recommender.recommend(userid, noOfRecommendations);
                for(RecommendedItem recommendation : recommendations)
                 {
                    System.out.println(recommendation.getItemID());
                }
                
            
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            System.out.println("there is an error");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
       catch (TasteException e) 
        {
            System.out.println("error");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        
    }
}
```

When I am running this code, I am not getting any output, although there is no error.I don't know what can be the problem. Can anyone figure out how to implement item-based similarity algorithm with Boolean data-set.

Comment: Debugging your code might not be a good fit here, as it is unlikely to be of interest to anyone other than you.

Answer (score 1):

The code and data combination is too small for predicting a solution. But note that you will not get any answer if there are no recommendations made. In this case there will be no exception either. Looks like your code

```
List<RecommendedItem> recommendations =
     recommender.recommend(userid, noOfRecommendations);
```

returned no recommendations. You should try with a variety of data.